# Create a simple TreeStore without using a model - Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to create a simple TreeStore without model, here is what I do :

```
var store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
    fields: ['name', 'area', 'children'],
    data: {
        name: 'Budget',
        area: 1,
        children: [{
            name: 'Defense',
            area: 0.5,
            children: []
        }, {
            name: 'Education',
            area: 0.3,
            children: []
        }, {
            name: 'Debt',
            area: 0.2,
            children: []
        }]
    }
});
```

But I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getReader' of undefined`, can someone tell me what I am missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that you are using an in-memory proxy:

```
var store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
    fields: ['name', 'area', 'children'],
    data: {
        text: 'Budget',
        area: 1,
        children: [{
            name: 'Defense',
            area: 0.5,
            children: []
        }, {
            name: 'Education',
            area: 0.3,
            children: []
        }, {
            name: 'Debt',
            area: 0.2,
            children: []
        }]
    },
    proxy : 'memory'
});
```